# performing create on related object in django stops code execution

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an object using the reverse side of the relation. (the many side).

I am encountering an issue that my code pretty much stops the moment I perform the actual create, it fails, but silently. Placing any statements after are not executed. The entire program does not fail or show any errors. Without any error statements or exceptions showing stacktraces, I cannot figure out what is actually wrong here.

Here is the aforementioned statement:

```
# Class method on Pot object

def create_static_notification(self, interval, duration, value_exceeded, is_high, measurement_type, level):
    self.staticnotification_set.create(
        interval=interval,
        duration=duration,
        value_exceeded=value_exceeded,
        is_high=is_high,
        measurement_type=measurement_type,
        level=level,
    )

    print 'I will never be printed ):'
```

The model it is trying to create an instance of is this:

```
class StaticNotification(models.Model):
    registered_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    dismissed_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_relevant = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    interval = models.DurationField()
    duration = models.DurationField()
    value_exceeded = models.FloatField()
    is_high = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    measurement_type = models.ForeignKey(StaticParameterType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    level = models.ForeignKey(ReportLevel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pot = models.ForeignKey(Pot, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have validated that all the fields that have to be there, are there.

*For extra context*: This code is run through a custom django command which runs on the MQTT protocol. Subsequent calls from MQTT are actually still working, the single call stops. Next calls go through, just this one part of the code doesn't work.

Comment: check your SQL statements in the logs. Are they being executed with correct parameters?

Comment: Just checked the logs, there are no SQL statements related to this model being executed. So it never reaches the SQL stage.

Comment: try to perform a creation without reverse side.

Comment: Same issue, no dice, SQL not being executed, code after the statement is never reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer and the source of my confusion. The problem lied entirely in a typo, seems like measurement_type was not the variable I parsed from a UTF-8 string, which causes a ValueError to be raised.

The issue was caught by a bad implementation of the stack, somewhere between resolution and my general exception handling ValueError was being caught with a mere pass statement following it.

This of course meant that the error was eaten and I wasn't made aware, which happens when any other error occurs.

Biggest lesson is, don't pass exceptions. Even if you are writing a stack in a hurry.